# thymeleaf used in Spring, adding a list to iterate over with th:each

Tags: spring, model, thymeleaf

I want to use the the th:each construct to create a table of items. I have problems with adding the data to the model. I used this contruct:

```
        model.addAllAttributes(repository.findByusername(username));
```

findByusername returns a java.Util.List of object. Then I always only have the last element in the list in the model. I gues that it depends on that the attribute namn is the class name so each addition of a new element in the list overrides the prviously added element.

How can I add each element as a separate attribute to the model and then easily iterate them with th:each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Controller is should be return,

```
model.addAttribute("usersList", repository.findByusername(username));
```

And your thymeleaf code is should be like,

```
  <th:block th:each="user : ${usersList}">
      <td th:text="${user.username}">Test</td>
  </th:block>
```